# Words that do not follow the 'Q' and 'U' Rule?

Tags: word-request

So here I am, with yet another simple question, something that remains unanswered for a long time. I've searched Google for a word that doesn't follow the rule-of-thumb that a 'U' always follows a 'Q' in any English word.  Google showed me a few words, but they aren't English words. Anybody know any examples that disobey this elementary rule ?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_containing_Q_not_followed_by_U) gave me a list of very weird and uncommon words that can be used as examples. But most of these are Anglicized from foreign languages and hardly ever used.

Comment: The same Wikipedia article gives examples. What more do you want?

Comment: The examples given by Wikipedia are not commonly used English words. Please go through the Wikipedia page. There are no proper English words in that list. I could say "BenQ"  is a word, but that is a pronoun. I wanted to know if anybody out here knows any commonly used words that satisfy my constrain.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker and any query I post here is to understand the language better. So any sort of help is appreciable.

Comment: *Qwerty* is a common English word. It is also (along with others) mentioned in the Wikipedia article. The first thing most people here are going to do in trying to answer your question is either is go to Wikipedia or do a Web search for something like *English words with q not followed by u*, which is something you could do.

Comment: That is something I've already done, and I have clearly mentioned it. Its not like Wikipedia has the answer to everything. There can be people who can suggest a few words. The internet doesn't have the answer to everything, people do. That's why I've put this up here.

Comment: *Qi* isn't actually that rare, but it's often spelled *chi* in English.

Comment: Is 'qwerty' a word ? Its a keyboard layout right ? Can we use it in a sentence ? Is it correct ?

Comment: All the other uses of the letter Q are simply writing a Q and telling everyone to say it like a K or Ch.

Comment: @snailboat, the Chinese word 'Chi' ?

Comment: *Qwerty* is a word. See the definition *and* example sentences in the [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/qwerty).

Comment: All right. Thanks @NES. I didn't know that.

Comment: @VarunKN Yep, the English word *qi, chi* borrowed from Mandarin 气 qì.  I'm just commenting because you said they were hardly ever used, but I hear this one pretty often.

Comment: Iraq and Qatar would be geographic names that depending on where you live these may be commonly heard that have a "Q" and aren't followed with a "U" as a couple of other examples. Also there is a character from "Star Trek: The Next Generation" known as "Q" that is just a letter without any "U" at all for another possibility depending on your requirements.

Comment: What's your definition of an "English word"? If it's in the English dictionary then it's a valid Scrabble play. If you're asking for only Greek, Latin, and Germanic derivations, then yeah, you're probably not going to find much.

Answer (score 3):

To quote the Wikipedia article you cite:

> the only modern-English words that contain Q not followed by U and are not borrowed from another language are *qiana*, *qwerty*, and *tranq*.

To me, *tranq* doesn't violate the norm because the *q* comes at the end of the word.

The same Wikipedia entry mentions many loan words, and it explicitly states that all of them are found in at least one dictionary of English, thus recognizing them as part of the English lexicon, that is, as English words.

The word *qi*, also spelled *chi*, is included in the [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/qi), as is the non loan word *[qwerty](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/qwerty)*.

In general the information in the Wikipedia article seems trustworthy  (this is not always the case).

Comment: IMO, all of those are kind of fake examples.  *Qiana* is a proper name, *qwerty* is a random string of letters that luckily happens to be pronounceable and only exists because of a historical accident, and *tranq* is only spelled that way because it's a shortening of *tranquilizer*, which does adhere to the rule.

Comment: All of that is true, @stangdon, but how does that make them 'fake'?

Comment: I'm saying that they aren't very useful or meaningful as examples of "English words" except maybe in the trivia game sense.  I mean, I could create something and name it "QQqQ*zGHb" but does that mean that "English words can have random capitalization, the same letter repeated four times, asterisks, and no vowels"?  Likewise, "qwerty" means absolutely nothing beyond self-reference.

Comment: I think I've seen the shortening of *tranquilizer* spelled as *trank* instead.  I haven't seen *tranq*.

Comment: @NateEldredge 'Tranq' is given as an alternate spelling of 'trank' ("slang abbreviation for 'tranquilizer'") in the OED. It also gives a 1973 usage of 'tranqs': *As late as four fifteen, mother flaked out: either the party had aggravated her sense of intraspecific alienation, or her tranqs, all day neutralized by adrenalin, had hit her together in one clammy punch.* --M. Amis, in Rachel Papers, p 196

Comment: "…a random string of letters that luckily happens to be pronounceable and only exists because of a historical accident" - isn't that the definition of every word?

Comment: I would add that qwerty has become a word because it is the name of the mostly widely used Latin character keyboard layout. FYI, qwerty is not completely random, it was designed by Shoes when he built the qwerty layout. The phase "qwerty keyboard" is common has a well defined meaning. This is how many words are created. Radar, scuba, laser are all invented words that are combinations of letters which have become common words.

Comment: @stangdon all you really showed is that these unusual words all have etymologies recent enough so that you know them and can explain why they are the way they are. All words have etymologies, *including* words that have unusual properties. You must not believe any rule has an exception, given that the exceptions all originated outside of the mainstream rule.